# Getting an object from a dictionary of objects

Tags: c#, object, dictionary, boxing

I'm trying to pull an object from a dictionary of objects, and return said object however I'm having a bit of a problem with types. The class in question looks something like this, I'm wondering how I go about returning the actual object rather than the variable (which I assume is a string by default).

```
 public Object GetObject(string foo){

 if(someDict.ContainsKey(foo))
 {
   var pulledObject = someDict[foo];

 }
  return pulledObject;
 }
```

I had thought boxing was needed, something like

```
 object pulledObject = someDict[foo];
```

But that doesn't seem to work, any advice that could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What should it return if the key doesn't exist?

Comment: You have a scope-issue. You're declaring your pulledObject inside the if-statement's scope, making it inaccessible outside for your return-statement to work.

Comment: Are you getting a compile error or does the program malfunction at runtime? "doesn't work" is a little vague.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't really say what isn't working, but you are on the right track.  Try something like this:

```
public Object GetObject(string foo){

  if (someDict.ContainsKey(foo))
    return someDict[foo];
  return null;
}
```

I suspect your problem was that you were getting a compile error with `pulledObject` which was in a child scope.

Update: As Jon Skeet points out, it's even better to use TryGetValue so you don't perform the lookup twice (once when doing ContainsKey, and again when you use the indexer []).  So, better solution is:

```
public Object GetObject(string foo){

  object pulledObject = null;
  someDict.TryGetValue(foo, out pulledObject);
  return pulledObject;
}
```

Comment: @JonSkeet, what is the difference between using `ContainsKey` and `TryGetValue`? The question is purely academic.

Comment: @BigM: With TryGetValue, you only need to do the lookup once: why would you perform the lookup once to check for presence (which *finds* the entry but then ignores the value), and then look the entry up again to get the value?

Comment: @JonSkeet, understood. My apologies. Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code is accurate, you have a scope-issue. You're declaring your pulledObject inside the if-statement's scope, making it inaccessible outside for your return-statement to work.

```
public Object GetObject(string foo)
{
    object pulledObject = null;
    if(someDict.ContainsKey(foo))
    {
        pulledObject = someDict[foo];
    }
    return pulledObject;
}
```

or (courtesy of Jon Skeet)

```
public Object GetObject(string foo)
{
    object pulledObject = null;
    someDict.TryGetValue(foo, out pulledObject);
    return pulledObject;
}
```

Comment: THe `if` statement in the second one is redundant. If `TryGetValue` returns false, pulledObject will already be null.

Comment: @JacobAbrahams I was JUST reading up on that, realising my redundancy-mistake. =)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code does not work is not that `pulledObject` has a wrong type, but because it's out of scope. You can do this:

```
public Object GetObject(string foo){
    if(someDict.ContainsKey(foo)) {
        return someDict[foo];
    }
    return null;
}
```

The users would call your `GetObject` as follows:

```
object res = GetObject(foo);
if (res == null) {
    // Object is not there - do something else
}
```

The disadvantage of this pattern is inability to distinguish situations when the object is there but it's `null` from situations when the object is not there. An approach more "native" to .NET's dictionary API would be to use `TryGetValue` instead of `GetObject`, like this:

```
object res;
if (someDict.TryGetValue(foo, out res)) {
} else {
    // Object is not there - do something else
}
```

This approach performs the lookup operation only once, saving the CPU (although insisting on using this approach for the alleged speed improvement would be a micro-optimization).